# How does ipython variable expansion works?

Tags: ipython, variable-expansion

I don't understand what the `${}` is doing in the fourth and sixth prompt, and I can't find any documentation about this, The book `Python for Unix and Linux System Administrator` has an example like the one in the sixth prompt, in which the variable is not only prepended of `$` but also enclosed in `{}` in order to embed the string inside another one, It works out if I quote the complete expression, but what's happening in [4 & 6]?:

```
In [1]: test = 'TEST TEST TEST!!!'                                                                                          

In [2]: !echo test
test                                                                                                                         

In [3]: !echo $test                                                                                                         
TEST TEST TEST!!!                                                                                                            

In [4]: !echo ${test}   # Don't understand this one.                                                                                                
TEST TEST!!!  

In [5]: !echo {test}                                                                                                       
TEST TEST TEST!!!

In [6]: !echo ${test}TEST!!!   # Nor this one either.
TEST TEST!!!TEST!!!

In [7]: !echo '${test}TEST!!!'
$TEST TEST TEST!!!TEST!!!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In[4], typo, `)` instead of `}` , otherwise I would guess that when dooing `${test}`, `{test}` is expended to `TEST TEST TEST`, leading to `$TEST TEST TEST` , and then `$TEST` is expended again (in shell I suppose).

I say that because :

```
In [1]: test = 'PATH TEST TEST!!!'

In [2]: !echo "${test}"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/pyt.../.rvm/bin TEST TEST!!!
```

But you have to be carefull, IPython does its own variable expansion, `$foo` or `{foo}` (no dollar sign) expand to **Python** value of foo. Wherease Shell often use `$FOO` or `${FOO}` (dollar AND Bracket).

In IPython, when using `!` you have to use double dollar `$$` for explicit dolar. not sure how to escape Brackets though.